# Pandas DataFrame.groupby including index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset taken from the Windows Eventlog. The `TimeGenerated` column is set as the index. I'd like to get an aggregated view showing me the number of events, by `EventType` (info/warn/err) and by the index value. I could use `resample()` to set the datetime resolution (day, business day, etc).

Here's my DataFrame:

[image: DataFrame]

```
log.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 80372 entries, 2015-08-31 12:15:23 to 2015-05-11 04:08:07
Data columns (total 4 columns):
EventID          80372 non-null int64
SourceName       80372 non-null object
EventType        76878 non-null object
EventCategory    80372 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(2), object(2)
memory usage: 3.1+ MB
```

I can of course group by the EventType, but this drops my index:

```
log[['EventID', 'EventType']].groupby('EventType').count('EventID')
```

[image: Grouped]

I would have to specify my existing index it in the call to `groupby()`, but how can I reference the index? Or do I have to perform a `reset_index()` before the `groupby()` call? Or am I simply going about this all wrong and is it painfully obvious that I'm a Pandas newbie? ;-)

Version info:

- Python 3.4.2
- pandas 0.16.2
- numpy 1.9.2

## Update

To clarify further, what I'd like to achieve is:

- A count of the EventIDs (the number of events)
- By EventType (in axis 1)
- By Timestamp (in axis 0)

Note that the Timestamp is not unique (in the raw DF), as multiple events can occur simultaneously.

One way I've been able to achieve what I wanted, is by doing:

```
temp = log.reset_index()
temp.groupby(['TimeGenerated','EventType']).count('EventID'['EventID'].unstack().fillna(0)
```

In that case, my output is:

[image: Grouped 2]

Which then allows me to resample the count further, e.g. :

```
temp.resample('MS', how='sum')
```

This works, but what I don't know if whether having to perform a `reset_index()` is necessary to achieve this grouping. Could I have done it in a better (read: more efficient) way?

Comment: What do you mean 'by index value'?  Each event is a timestamp, so your raw DF is already by index value.  Do you want to add a column in your DF for the year_month, for example, and then include that in your grouping?

Comment: You can create dummies using `pd.get_dummies(df.eventtype)`.  Then just groupby date and sum over those new columns you added.

Comment: @BrianPendleton Very true! However (though I realise this wasn't part of the original question) if I want to add another column (e.g. get a count of events by event type and hostname, by timestamp), would this approach still work?

Comment: If I have to do that kind of aggregation work, I usually put all the variables I'll need to group on as the index.  Then just use the `level` parameter of the group by method.  Or you can just do a reset index at the beginning and just group over the columns instead of worrying about indexing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I was missing is that you can perform a `groupby()` on one or more levels of your index.

```
test = log.set_index('EventType', append=True)
test = test.groupby(level=[0,1])['EventID'].count('EventID')
test.unstack().fillna(0)
```

Alternatively, the suggestion by Brian Pendleton worked as well:

```
pd.get_dummies(log.EventType)
```

The difference with this last approach is that it doesn't work as well if you need to add another level in your column axis (e.g. by Hostname). But that wasn't part of the original question of course.